# How to compare the object with boolean value in cshtml

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi i am new in C# i have `ob.ValAfter` in .cshtml page which is a object `@ob.ValAfter` is showing 1 or 0 instead of that i want to show True instead of 1 and false instead of 0 iam using following code in cshtml

```
if (ob.Prop == "VendorMaterialTypeID")
{
  ob.ValAfter == 1 ? "True" : "False";
  ob.ValBefore == 0 ? "True" : "False";
}
```

but it is showing me operator == can not be applied Please suggest me how can i  campare value of the object so i can show true or false in UI

My model code is 
   public object ValAfter { get; set; }.

Comment: Why is it an `object`?  If it's going to store an integer value, make it an `int`.

Comment: @David it is an object because it shows different before and after value like StatusBeforeValue, StatusAfterValue like that

Comment: @David for Particular property "VendorMaterialTypeID" it is showing 1 or 0 i just want to show True or false instead